# Custom validation method that accesses other model properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

I'm attempting to create a custom validation method for one of my entities, so I've created a class that inherits from `ValidationAttribute`:

```
public class OneWheelchairPerTrainAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        // This is where I need to access the other entity property
    }
}
```

What I'm struggling with is how I access the other properties on the entity. This is my entity:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int TimetableId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Wheelchair { get; set; }

    public virtual Timetable Timetable { get; set; }
}
```

The validation annotation I'm writing will be applied to the `Wheelchair` property, and I need to access the `TimetableId` property from within my validation method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [IsValid overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd730022(v=vs.110).aspx) to pass in a ValidationContext, like this:

```
public class OneWheelchairPerTrainAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
  public override bool IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
  {
    Object instance = context.ObjectInstance;
    Type type = instance.GetType();
    // Here is your timetableId
    Object timeTableId = type.GetProperty("TimetableId ").GetValue(instance, null);

    //Do validation ...
   }
}
```

Comment: There is no public override for that method.  You have to use "protected override ValidationResult IsValid..."

Answer (score 6):

Another (in my opinion, better) way  to validate multiple properties is by doing it on `class` level.

**This not the exact same situation as in your answer, but it still involves multiple property validation.**

*Imagine you want to allow a wheelchair to be an id or a new object, but you still want to allow only one:*

An example of my `ExactlyOneRequired` attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class ExactlyOneRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string FirstPropertyName { get; set; }
    public string SecondPropertyName { get; set; }

    //Constructor to take in the property names that are supposed to be checked
    public ExactlyOneRequiredAttribute(string firstPropertyName, string secondPropertyName)
    {
        FirstPropertyName = firstPropertyName;
        SecondPropertyName = secondPropertyName;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null) 
           return new ValidationResult("Object must have a value;");

        var neededProperties = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperties().Where(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.Name == FirstPropertyName || propertyInfo.Name == SecondPropertyName).Take(2).ToArray();
        var value1 = neededProperties[0].GetValue(value);
        var value2 = neededProperties[1].GetValue(value);

        if (value1 == null | value2 == null)
            return ValidationResult.Success;

        return FailedValidationResult();
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name) => $"One of the fields: '{FirstPropertyName} or {SecondPropertyName}' is required, it is not allowed to set both.";

    private ValidationResult FailedValidationResult() => new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(FirstPropertyName), new List<string> {FirstPropertyName, SecondPropertyName});
}
```

Usage:

```
[ExactlyOneRequired(nameof(WheelChairId), nameof(WheelChair))]
public class Train
{
    public int? WheelChairId { get; set; }

    public WheelChair WheelChair { get; set; }
}
```

You can of course expect as many properties as you want and make it as *generic* as you want. My point is, instead of *string checking* on property name within the attribute, *injecting* the property names is the *cleaner* way to go,